# pthread larger projects

Tags: coding-style, open-source, pthreads, projects-and-solutions

I'm looking for more practical larger projects that use the pthreads library, but unable to find any.  Nothing too complicated, but more on the larger scale from the pthread examples you find in tutorials online.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks, Kerx

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=pthread&type=cs

Comment: Appreciate it, I didn't even know google had a code search.  Something very useful for me! +1